# ROS DDS support for IPv6

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, network, mesh, ros-iron

The big question is: Does ROS2 (humble or iron mainly) support IPv6?

With some really basic testing, it would seem that out of the box the answer is no. I started a publisher from the minimal examples package on one machine. On another machine, running "ros2 topic list" did not yield the topic. I did confirm that these computers could ping each other over IPv6 only.

I'm particularly interested in using IPv6 because my robots will communicate with each other via highly dynamic mesh networks. I'd prefer not to manually configure static IPv4 addresses for members of the mesh, and APIPA address assignment for IPv4 (afaik) does not yield predictable addresses. IPv6 addresses on the other hand, if my understanding is correct, can be assigned based on SLAAC and will be predictable based on the MAC address of the network interfaces.

Fingers crossed someone knows of a DDS middle-ware configuration that allows IPv6 comms.